# Laravel route cache missing entries

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I have defined a custom service provider:

```
class DomainServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->tenants()->each(function (Tenant $tenant) {
            $this->registerWebRoutes($tenant);
        });
    }

    protected function registerWebRoutes(Tenant $tenant): void
    {
        Route::group([
            'as' => "{$tenant->namespace}.", // e.g. foo.
            'domain' => $tenant->domain, // e.g. foo.com
            'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function () use ($tenant) {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(app_path("Domain/{$tenant->name}/Routes/web.php"));
        });
    }
```

I can see all the routes using `php artisan route:list`, however when optimizing with `php artisan route:cache`, the routes don't get included into the cache. It seems they are removed, and I don't know why.

The namespace and domain are unique.

Thanks!

Comment: Which tenant system are you using?

Comment: what routes don't get included? ... since what you have here is dynamic you would only end up with a single static version of those routes

Comment: @Flame I'm using Spatie multitenancy

Comment: @lagbox All routes are working fine without caching, however using caching, they simple seems to be gone. I'm following the instructions from this page: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/using-tasks-to-prepare-the-environment/switching-route-cache-paths